# EWS fetch read/unread mails from specific user in Java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

How can I specify the `SearchFilter` with Java EWS library to fetch mail from a specific user?

In `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemSchema`, I could find something like "IsFromMe" but this will check for current User.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to get emails from a Mailbox other than your own, or find emails you have received from someone else?

Comment: received ones. I think the answer below might work. I have to try though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The From/To type information isn't on `ItemSchema` it's on `EmailMessageSchema`. Call would look something like this:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
//login to your exchange server with credentials etc & set your service url
.....

//issue your search for a given user using EmailMesssageSchema.From  
FindItemsResults <Item> results = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, 
new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.From, "SomeUser"), new ItemView(100));
```

Comment: Ahh, good to hear, glad I could help! Can you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Adding 1 more point, we can use `Or` clause for `SearchFilter` to specify more then one User.